# Import XCTest into a dynamic framework

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, xctest

I have a project where I have created a dynamic framework. Inside the framework itself, not the framework's tests, I have the following file:

```
import Foundation
import XCTest


public func assertThrowsException(function: () throws -> Void) {
    XCTAssertTrue(doesItThrowException(function))
}


public func assertDoesNotThrowsException(function: () throws -> Void) {
    XCTAssertFalse(doesItThrowException(function))
}


private func doesItThrowException(function: () throws -> Void) -> Bool {
    do {
        let _ = try function()
    } catch {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

They are utility methods to assert that a clojure is raising an exception. It's to make up for the missing Swift's `XCTAssertThrows()`.

Of course I have to import the `XCTest` framework to be able to use `XCTAssert`* methods. But I am not able to achieve it.
I keep receiving an error that a framework with that name is not available.

Do you have any idea how to successfully import `XCTest`?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 25):

I've run into similar issue and used build settings from [Nimble](https://github.com/Quick/Nimble) project. To fix issue:

1: Add to Other Linker Flags:

`-weak_framework
XCTest
-weak-lswiftXCTest`

2: Add to Framework Search Paths:

`$(DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR)
$(PLATFORM_DIR)/Developer/Library/Frameworks`

Now dynamic framework can import XCTest.

Sidenote: I also wanted to write something similar. I've ended up creating [mini-framework for unit testing error handling in Swift](https://github.com/mr-v/AssertThrows), maybe someone will find it useful. Works both with CocoaPods and Carthage.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! Shouldn't this be the accepted answer? @jollyr0ger

Comment: is there a better way to do this in 2020? this works, but it seems like such a long round about way to do something that should be simple :/

Answer (score 1):

Under Build Settings for your target, set `Enable Testing Search Paths` to `Yes`.

```
ENABLE_TESTING_SEARCH_PATHS = YES
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a `framework` using `Cocoapods`, you need to add the `XCTest` in your `.podspec` file:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|

  ...
  spec.framework = 'XCTest'

end
```