# Not able to use XCTUnwrap in Test Framework

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, frameworks, xctest

I am trying to create a test Framework that includes some extensions. I am able to `import XCTest` in the framework by following the suggestions from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35102636/3475906

However, whenever I try to use XCTUnwrap I got error: `Use of unresolved identifier 'XCTUnwrap'`

Basically, I want something like this:

```
import XCTest

extension Optional {
    func unwrap() -> Wrapped {
        do {
            return try XCTUnwrap(self)
        } catch {
            print("Handle error")
        }
    }
}
```

Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Are you able to use any other XCT symbols? for example XCTAssertEqual?

Comment: Yes @Sanich They work fine. Only issue is with XCTUnwrap as far as I see. Swift Language version is Swift 5 also.

Comment: Definitely using Xcode 11?

Comment: Sure I am using Xcode 11.3 @SebJachec

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `XCTUnwrap` API is only available in primary test bundle targets and not in other libraries or frameworks. There are two ways to fix this issue:

1. Move your `Optional` extension to the main bundle which obviously not something you want to do :)
2. Modify the following build settings in your test framework target:

```
SYSTEM_FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = (
    "$(inherited)",
    "$(PLATFORM_DIR)/Developer/Library/Frameworks",
);
LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = (
    "$(inherited)",
    "$(PLATFORM_DIR)/Developer/usr/lib",
);
SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS = "$(inherited) $(PLATFORM_DIR)/Developer/usr/lib"
```

Answer (score 0):

At least since Xcode 11.4 you may just enable:

ENABLE_TESTING_SEARCH_PATHS = YES

in the "Build Settings" of your project or target.